# Click evt is registered to div surrounding checkbox instead of the checkbox itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, checkbox

I have a list of documents with a checkbox next to each. Clicking on a checkbox is supposed to append that document to a separate div (aka a "Favorites List"). This does not work, but clicking on the div that *surrounds* the checkbox appends that document correctly. Another issue is that clicking on a checkbox when the Favorites contains one or more documents clears the list.

**How can I properly register the checkbox itself to the click event rather than the div surrounding the checkbox?** I've tried different methods, such as 
`$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).on("click", faveFunc)`, but I've been coming up short so I thought I'd ask about it here.

#### JS snippet:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

var tableRes = '';

  export default class {
      constructor() {
        this.loadTableData();
      }

// this area contains code that's irrelevant //

// ------ Rendering checkboxes ------- //
  $("#km-table-id tbody tr").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    if (evt.target.type !== "checkbox") {
      $(":checkbox", this).on("click");
    }      
  });

  // ------ Appending checkboxes ------- //
  let inputType = $("<input />", {"type": "checkbox"})
  let chkboxCol = $("#km-table-id tbody tr > td:nth-child(3)");

  chkboxCol.append(inputType).addClass("checkbox-class");


  // --- My Favorites functionality ---- //
  function faveFunc(evt) {
    let anchor = $($(evt.target).prev().find("a")[0]).clone();
    // let ancTxt = $(anchor).text();
    switch($(".populate-faves").find("a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").length)
    {
      case 0:
        $(".populate-faves").append(anchor);
        break;
      default:
        $(".populate-faves > a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").remove();
        break;
    }
  };


  function newList() {
    let data = $(evt.target).prev().find("a").eq(0).html();
    let outputList = $(".populate-faves");

    $(".populate-faves").html("");

    $("#km-table-id tbody tr)").each(function(i, el) {
        let cntxFave = $(".add-id", el);
        let fave = $(".checkbox-class", el);
        let itemText = $(data, el);

        if(cntxFave.is(".add-id")) {
          outputList.append("<li>" + itemText.html() + "</li>");
        }

        if(fave.prop("checked")) {
          outputList.append("<li>" + itemText.html() + "</li>");
        }
      });
  }; // ------------ newList

  $(".checkbox-class").on("click", faveFunc);
```

#### HTML snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-14"> <!-- Right -->

        <table id="km-table-id" class="cell-border display stripe-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <!-- <th></th> -->
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th></th> <!-- Keep here--this is for checkbox col -->
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody></tbody> 
    </table>
```

```js
import $ from 'jquery';

import dt from 'datatables.net';

var categories = '';
var tableRes = '';

export default class {
  constructor() {
    this.loadCategoryData();
    this.loadTableData();
  }
  
let KMdocs = {
  {
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "[redacted]",
          "uri": "[redacted]",
          "etag": "\"2\"",
          "type": "[redacted]"
        },
        "File": {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "[redacted]",
            "uri": "[redacted]",
            "type": "SP.File"
          },
          "Name": "Guide to Product IDs.docx"
        },
        "FileLeafRef": "Guide to Product IDs.docx",
        "ResourceType": {
          "__metadata": {
            "type": "Collection(SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue)"
          },
          "results": [
            {
              "Label": "Guides \uff06 Protocols",
              "TermGuid": "[redacted]",
              "WssId": 706
            }
          ]
        },
        "EncodedAbsUrl": "[redacted]"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "[redacted]",
          "uri": "[redacted]",
          "etag": "\"3\"",
          "type": "SP.Data.KMDocumentsItem"
        },
        "File": {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "[redacted]",
            "uri": "[redacted]",
            "type": "SP.File"
          },
          "Name": "LRRP Template 1.docx"
        },
        "FileLeafRef": "LRRP Template 1.docx",
        "ResourceType": {
          "__metadata": {
            "type": "Collection(SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue)"
          },
          "results": [
            {
              "Label": "Templates",
              "TermGuid": "[redacted]",
              "WssId": 941
            },
            {
              "Label": "Guides \uff06 Protocols",
              "TermGuid": "[redacted]",
              "WssId": 706
            }
          ]
        },
        "EncodedAbsUrl": "[redacted]"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "[redacted]",
          "uri": "[redacted]",
          "etag": "\"3\"",
          "type": "SP.Data.KMDocumentsItem"
        },
        "File": {
          "__metadata": {
            "id": "[redacted]",
            "uri": "[redacted]",
            "type": "SP.File"
          },
          "Name": "LRRP Template 2.docx"
        },
        "FileLeafRef": "LRRP Template 2.docx",
        "ResourceType": {
          "__metadata": {
            "type": "Collection(SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue)"
          },
          "results": [
            {
              "Label": "Templates",
              "TermGuid": "[redacted]",
              "WssId": 941
            },
            {
              "Label": "Guides \uff06 Protocols",
              "TermGuid": "[redacted]",
              "WssId": 706
            }
          ]
        },
        "EncodedAbsUrl": "[redacted]"
      }
    ]
  }
}
}


  // ------ Loading Category data ------ // 
  loadCategoryData() {
    let res = KMdocs.d.results.filter(function(val) {
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {
      return {
        "FileName": obj.FileLeafRef,
        "Titles": obj.File.Name,
        "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
        "Categories": obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
          return val.Label;
        }).join(";")
      };
    });

    let label = KMdocs.d.results.filter(function(val) {
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {
      return obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
        return val.Label;
      })
    });

    // ---------- Unique Categs. --------- //
    let unique = [];
    let temp = KMdocs.d.results.filter(function(val) {
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).forEach(function(obj) {
      obj.ResourceType.results.forEach(function(val) {
        let divCat = document.createElement("div");
        $(divCat).attr("category", encodeURIComponent(val.Label));
        $(divCat).html(val.Label);
        if (!unique.includes(divCat.outerHTML)) {
          unique.push(divCat.outerHTML); // value can be anything, only keys matter
        }
      })
    });

    let categories = unique.sort();
    $(".indiv-label").append(categories);

  } // ------------- loadCategoryData()




  // ------ Loading doc title data ----- //
  loadTableData() {
    // Local icons exist under /SiteAssets/images, if needed //
    function docType(fileName) {
      let docImg = "<img src='[redacted]/Current.ashx/docx.gif'  />"
      let msgImg = "<img src='[redacted]/Current.ashx/msg.gif'   />"
      let nrlImg = "<img src='[redacted]/Current.ashx/nrl.gif'   />"
      let pdfImg = "<img src='[redacted]/Current.ashx/pdf.gif'   />"
      let pptImg = "<img src='[redacted]/Current.ashx/pptx.gif'  />"
      let xlsImg = "<img src='[redacted]/Current.ashx/xls.gif'   />"

      let docStr = fileName.split(".") // .split() seems to be necessary to render the icons
      for (var i = 0; i < docStr.length; i++) {
        if (docStr[i].includes('doc')) {
          return docStr[i] = docImg;
        } // -
        else if (docStr[i].includes('DOCX')) {
          return docStr[i] = docImg;
        } // -
        else if (docStr[i].includes('rtf')) {
          return docStr[i] = docImg;
        } // -
        else if (docStr[i].includes('msg')) {
          return docStr[i] = msgImg;
        } //
        else if (docStr[i].includes('nrl')) {
          return docStr[i] = nrlImg;
        } //
        else if (docStr[i].includes('pdf')) {
          return docStr[i] = pdfImg;
        } // 
        else if (docStr[i].includes('ppt')) {
          return docStr[i] = pptImg;
        } // -
        else if (docStr[i].includes('PPT')) {
          return docStr[i] = pptImg;
        } // -
        else if (docStr[i].includes('potx')) {
          return docStr[i] = pptImg;
        } // -
        else if (docStr[i].includes('xls')) {
          return docStr[i] = xlsImg;
        } //
      }
    } // docType


    $.noConflict();
    let tableRes = KMdocs.d.results.filter(function(val) {
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {
      return {
        "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
        "Titles": obj.File.Name,
        "Categories": obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
          return val.Label;
        }).join(";"),
        "Blank": "", // use to create an empty column, if necessary
        "docImg": docType(obj.File.Name) // Icon
      }
    })


    // --------- Rendering table --------- //
    $('#km-table-id').DataTable({
      data: tableRes,
      columns: [{
          data: "Categories"
        }, // available but hidden
        {
          data: "docImg",
          sortable: false
        }, // hides sorting arrows in icon col
        {
          data: "Titles"
        }, 
        {
          data: "Blank",
          sortable: false
        }
      ],
      columnDefs: [{
          data: "Path",
          ordering: true,
          targets: [2],
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            return $('<a>')
              .attr({
                target: "_blank",
                href: row.Path
              })
              .text(data)
              .wrap('<div></div>')
              .parent()
              .html();
          },
        },
        {
          searchable: true,
          targets: [0],
          visible: false
        }, // hides Categories col
      ],
      language: {
        searchPlaceholder: "Search All Documents"
      },
      lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500],
      order: [],
      pageLength: 500, // showing multiple pgs doesn't render all checkboxes...but initially showing all items renders them
      paging: true,
      pagingType: "full_numbers",
      responsive: true,
      scrollCollapse: true,
      scrollXInner: true,
      scrollY: 550,
      sDom: '<"top">rt<"bottom"flp><"left">' // affixes dropdown on bottom
    });


    // ------ Rendering checkboxes ------- //
    $("#km-table-id tbody tr").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      if (evt.target.type !== "checkbox") {
        $(":checkbox", this).on("click");
      }
    });

    // ------ Appending checkboxes ------- //
    let inputType = $("<input />", {
      "type": "checkbox"
    })
    let chkboxCol = $("#km-table-id tbody tr > td:nth-child(3)");

    chkboxCol.append(inputType).addClass("checkbox-class");


    // --- My Favorites functionality ---- //
    function faveFunc(evt) {
      let anchor = $($(evt.target).prev().find("a")[0]).clone();
      switch ($(".populate-faves").find("a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").length) {
        case 0:
          $(".populate-faves").append(anchor);
          break;
        default:
          $(".populate-faves > a:contains(" + $(anchor).text() + ")").remove();
          break;
      }
    };


    function newList() {
      let data = $(evt.target).prev().find("a").eq(0).html();
      let outputList = $(".populate-faves");

      $(".populate-faves").html("");

      $("#km-table-id tbody tr)").each(function(i, el) {
        let cntxFave = $(".add-id", el);
        let fave = $(".checkbox-class", el);
        let itemText = $(data, el);

        if (cntxFave.is(".add-id")) {
          outputList.append("<li>" + itemText.html() + "</li>");
        }

        if (fave.prop("checked")) {
          outputList.append("<li>" + itemText.html() + "</li>");
        }
      });
    }; // ------------ newList

    $(":checkbox").on("click", faveFunc);

    $("#add-id").on("click", faveFunc); // does not work






    



    // Linking custom search w/ DT search  //

    let oTable = $("#km-table-id").DataTable();
    $("#searchbar").on("input", function() {
      oTable.search($(this)
        .val() + " " + decodeURIComponent($(this)
          .attr("category"))).draw();
    })

  } // ------------------ loadTableData 






} // ------------- export default class
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Pages - KM</title>
  <meta name="description" content="description here">
  <meta name="keywords" content="keywords,here">

  <!-- DataTables CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/css/select.dataTables.min.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="KMStyles.css" type="text/css">



  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!------------------------------->

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

  <!------------------------------->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.6.2/core.min.js"></script>





  <script type="text/javascript" src="SiteAssets/scripts/getListItems.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <script src="./bundle.js"></script>

  <div class="km-div-container">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Left -->

      <span class="KM-title"><h1>KM</h1></span>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input category="" class="form-control" daysprior="" id="searchbar" input-all="" placeholder="Search All Documents..." type="search">
      </div>

      <div id="myFave.hs-gc-header" class="faves-div">
        <p style="font-weight:bold">My Favorites:</p>

        <div class="populate-faves"></div>
        <!-- location of favorited documents -->
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-------------------------------------------->

    <div class="col-md-3" id="middle-id">
      <!-- Middle -->

      <p>
        <div class="all-docs-title" category="" style="font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer" input="">All Documents</div>
      </p>
      <p>
        <div class="recently-added-title" category="" days="30" style="cursor:pointer;">Recently Added and/or Modified</div>
      </p>

      <div id="km-labels">
        <a>
          <p class="indiv-label" style="cursor:pointer;"></p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-------------------------------------------->

    <div class="col-md-14">
      <!-- Right -->

      <table id="km-table-id" class="cell-border display stripe-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <!-- <th></th> -->
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th></th>
            <!-- Keep here--this is for checkbox col -->
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody></tbody>

      </table>

      <!-- <ul class="custom-menu">
          <li data-action="open" id="open-id">Open Document</li>
          <li data-action="add" id="add-id">Set As Favorite</li>
          <li data-action="email">Email Document</a></li>
        </ul> -->

    </div>
    <!-- col-md-14 -->



    <!-- <div class="kmdialog"></div> -->
    <!-- what is this? -->



  </div>
  <!-- km-div-container -->


</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The core of the demo is the following:
                `event.type` ⇩        `Event Handler` ⇩

> ```
> $(document).on('change', 'CHECKBOX', addFav);
> ```

⇧ `event.currentTarget`     ⇧ `event.target`

---

**Demo Outline**

- Assign each checkbox a `data-*` attribute with a unique value. **ex.** `data-id="1"`
- To reference and clone an element in a table cell placed before the table cell with the checkbox, **ex.**:

  ```
  $(event.target).closest('td').prev('td').find(ANCHOR).clone();
  ```
- Use the `data-*` attribute of the checkbox to associate it with the cloned element in the example below the cloned anchor is appended to a `<li>`, **ex.**:

  ```
  $(LI).addClass('fav'+ID).append(ANCHOR);
  ```
- The association is used to remove the `<li>` from the favorites list when the checkbox is unchecked, **ex.**:

  ```
  $('.fav'+ID).remove();
  ```

**Review demo in full page mode**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    caption {
      caption-side: top;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      font-weight: 400
    }
    
    .favorite {
      list-style: none
    }
    
    .favorite li::before {
      content: '\1f49a\a0\a0'
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="container">
    <section class='row'>
      <fieldset class="col-md-12">
        <legend>&#128150; Favorites:</legend>
        <ul class='favorite'></ul>
      </fieldset>
    </section>
  </header>
  <hr>
  <main class='container'>
    <section class='row'>
      <article class="col-md-12">
        <table class='table'>
          <caption>Data</caption>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Link</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class='table-bordered'>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <a href='#/' class='lnx'>LINK 1: Category I</a></td>
              <td>
                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input class="chx custom-control-input" type="checkbox" data-id='1'>
      <b class="custom-control-indicator"></b>
      <b class="custom-control-description"> &#128153;</b>
   </label>
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <a href='#/' class='lnx'>LINK 2: Category II</a></td>
              <td>
                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input class="chx custom-control-input" type="checkbox" data-id='2'>
      <b class="custom-control-indicator"></b>
      <b class="custom-control-description"> &#128153;</b>
   </label>
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <a href='#/' class='lnx'>LINK 3: Category III</a></td>
              <td>
                <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input class="chx custom-control-input" type="checkbox" data-id='3'>
      <b class="custom-control-indicator"></b>
      <b class="custom-control-description"> &#128153;</b>
   </label>
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on('change', '.chx', addFav);

    function addFav(e) {
      var tgt = e.target;
      var ID = $(tgt).data('id');
      if (tgt.checked) {
        var lnx = $(tgt).closest('td').prev('td').find('.lnx').clone();
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        $('.favorite').append(item);
        $(item).addClass('fav' + ID).append(lnx);
        return false;
      } else if (!tgt.checked) {
        $('.fav' + ID).remove();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```